# Open an application and stay on terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, application

I want to open an application from terminal and stay on terminal not switch the window the opened app. I know I can open app for example for sublime I can enter `subl` and etc.  I have tried to run `subl &`, `subl -a`, `subl -g`. All commands opens and switches the window to app. I want the screen to stay on terminal and open the app as well.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I get the new window to not grab the keyboard focus?" and / or  "How do I get the new window to not open in front of the current window?"

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I'm guessing the latter. If my guess it's correct it's a job for Window Manager or a tool such as devilspie

Comment: what I am actually trying to do is. I am running a series of command first cd then source then open subl and then run a server. Everything is working fine.  Only thing which I want is when it open subl (subl comes on window) if I press ALT+TAB it will go back to terminal . I just want to stay on terminal and not to show subl. I do not want to press ALT+TAB

Comment: @Sense-pro Your comment is hard to follow and long. Correct me if I am wrong. You are saying yet to both of my suggestions. "how do I get the new window to not grab the keyboard focus?" and / or "How do I get the new window to not open in front of the current window?" If so then edit the question to make it clear. Feel free to use my words.

Answer (score -1):

You can use screen.

Example:

> screen python3 run.py

Then you can press Ctrl + A + D - It will detach .
You can work from the same terminal.

Note that to resume you need the pid (e.g. 1234)

Then to resume:

> screen -r 1234

Comment: I don't see how this changes OP's problem that a window opens and gets the focus when they run a program like `subl`. It seems to me that you misunderstood the question (which, to be fair, is hard to understand).